# encrypt file with php and public key

Tags: php, file

I generated a key pair (public and private), and from console by:

`openssl smime -encrypt -aes256 -in backup.sql -binary -DEM -out outform backup_encrypted.sql public_key.pem`

I encrypt the file correctly. Sql, as I can do this with php? I've tried several and nothing Functions

Here I leave one of them.

```
$data=file_get_contents("backup.sql");
$key=file_get_contents("public_key.pem");
openssl_public_encrypt($data,$output,$key);
echo $output;
```

$output returns nothing ..
Thank you.

Comment: Before encrypting a file.. Are you using a two way encryption? one to passively encrypt so it cannot be read, and another to decrypt so it can be read?

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at [the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-public-encrypt.php#31311), you have to give **the path** of the public key:

```
$data=file_get_contents("backup.sql");
$key="file://path/to/public_key.pem";
openssl_public_encrypt($data,$output,$key);
echo $output;
```

Comment: not work.. openssl_public_encrypt works with large text files?

Comment: and got to see the record and get this .. what I was saying .. is there any solution? "error:0406B06E:rsa routines:RSA_padding_add_none:data too large for key size"tt

Comment: @AitorChicharro What if you tried: `openssl_public_encrypt($data,$output,$key, OPENSSL_NO_PADDING);` ?

Answer (score 1):

you can you file_get_contents(), as example:

```
$data=file_get_contents("backup.sql");
$key= file_get_contents('public_key.pem');
openssl_public_encrypt($data,$output,$key);
echo $output;
```

I checked this snippets and its working.